# Stop Cassette from minifying a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, .net, minify, cassette

I'm using [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/) to minify my JavaScript. I don't want Cassette to minify one of my JavaScript files because it's causing an error. I'd rather use the already minified version provided by the original library authors.

How can I add a JavaScript file to Cassette without it minifying the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code for Cassette 1.x to create a IAssetTransformer that doesn't perform any minification

```cs
public class NoMinification : IAssetTransformer
{
    public NoMinification() {}

    public Func<Stream> Transform(Func<Stream> openSourceStream, IAsset asset)
    {
        return openSourceStream;
    }
}
```

And then update your CassetteConfiguration to put the already minified file it's own bundle, because you have to set the minifier for all of the files in a single bundle. If this javascript file has a dependency on another file, which will minified by cassette and end up in it's own bundle, you can use .AddReference as I show in the commented out line.

```cs
public class CassetteConfiguration : ICassetteConfiguration
{
    public void Configure(BundleCollection bundles, CassetteSettings settings)
    {
        //So, we set a no-op minifier for this bundle and force it into it's own bundle.
        bundles.Add<ScriptBundle>("Scripts/already-minified-file.min.js", b => {
            b.Processor = new ScriptPipeline { Minifier = new NoMinification() };
            //b.AddReference("~/Scripts/dependent-scripts.js");
        });
    }
}
```