# Stop Cassette v2 from minifying a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, minify, cassette

We are using [Cassette v2](http://getcassette.net/documentation/v2/) to concat and minify JavaScript files in a C# ASP.NET MVC5 project.

However, one of the dependencies uses eval to invoke some functions by name, which causes an error when the pipeline minifies the bundle.

I found [this SO answer about Cassette v1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980458/stop-cassette-from-minifying-a-javascript-file), but I need to configure a single bundle to *not* be minified in Cassette **v2**.

The current configuration is:

```
public void Configure(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add<ScriptBundle>("~/bundles/uicomponents", new[] { "~/Scripts/bridge/UIComponents.js" })
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

After a week of trying things only my own I was able to figure it out. You can customise the default Cassette Pipeline collection to remove the minifier by using the "customizeBundle" parameter:

```
        bundles.Add<ScriptBundle>("~/bundles/uicomponents", new[] { $"~/Scripts/bridge/UIComponents.js" },
            b =>
            {
                var minifyidx = b.Pipeline.IndexOf<MinifyAssets>(); //Don't want to re-minify scripts
                if (minifyidx >= 0) { b.Pipeline.RemoveAt(minifyidx); } //Remove the object from the cassette pipeline
            }
            );
```

Big thanks to everyone who helped answer, hopefully this saves someone else a headache!

Comment: this indeed helped, however, if you have multiple bundles it affects all the bundles. I added your example and it fixed my issue, but now all my bundles are not being minified. Ideally, I wanted only one bundle not to be minified. Any Suggestion is much appreciated.